# Perform action when user comes "Back" to your site

Tags: javascript

Google does this thing where on search results after you've visited a search result page and don't find what you and and click "back" to the Google Results there's then a "Hide results from xxxxxxxxxxx.com".

This doesn't happen till you're back on Google's page because I can see the effect.  How is this done?  Is it a onFocus on the window with a record of you having clicked that search result or something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess they simply just track how much time you spent on the result website and if you didn't spend much time there, they will assume you didn't find what you want? So in overly simplistic way:

1. When you click a search result, save a timestamp and the target website url in a cookie. This can be done by a simple onclick handler, it fires before you are taken to the new site.
2. You click back and the time is checked against the clicked time and the url is added to remove results from xxxxx.com if the time spent is < y seconds.

Then again I am just guessing and as I cannot get this functionality to work for me, I cannot find out to be even remotely sure. But If I ever had to implement something like this, this would be something I would explore first.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the search URL: it's `http://www.google.com/#sclie...`. The page doesn't actually reload, the results are loaded with Ajax. When you press Back, however, it does reload, or rather, `onload` and related events are raised again.